# Finding a way to load appropriate jars in different OSs as per requirement

Tags: java, windows, unix, jvm, classloader

This discussion involves getting a way to load different jars in different Operating Systems.

### Case Scenario

I am working on a specific OS known as NSK. Its an unix flavour and powers the HP NSK Servers. I am running one of my middleware app ( a java application) on NSK. The requirement is to make this app off-platform. i.e. it must work in other platforms like LINUX or Windows as well.

To implement this, I introduced 1 more jar. Now I need to introduce a logic where-in the JVM must load the appropriate jar at runtime (jar1 on NSK and jar2 on any other non-NSK platform). I used the following logic to implement:

Code:

```
if (System.getProperty(os.name).equals("NSK"))
     load jar1
else 
     load jar2
```

The above code works fine until I hit one of the Security exceptions "SecurityException" in getProperty API used above. This tells that the user running the app does not have necessary permission to use getProperty(). So, the above logic goes for a toss here.

Is there any way to tackle this exception and still be able to find out OS details and load the correct jar? Or better, are there any better logic to implement the same?

Please refer the below link for more details about getProperty(..)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Pabitra

Answer (score 0):

Given that Java is platform independent and only loads the classes you use, I would have one JAR which has everything you need and only load the class which are appropriate for your platform.

Doing what you suggest requires a sub class loader which just add complexity which doesn't appear to be needed.

If you can't access a system property you can actively test your library and see which one work on your system.  I am sure there is a method or class which working in one case but not the other or your wouldn't need two sets of code.

Comment: even if I use only a single jar, still I would end up requiring to find the platform I am currently running in to allow appropriate classes to be loaded from this jar. Please correct if I am wrong here

Comment: What would happen if you didn't and just used one and if it failed used the other.  You could do this once startup and cache your choice. If they both work fine on both platforms I would assume you don't need two in the first place.

Comment: Yeah this sounds logical. Thanks. However, this is a probable solution assuming that I have got 2 jars. Now, if I changed my design to have only a single jar(for better compatibility with existing users using my app), then I am still at crossroads right? Assume I have 3 classes inside that. Class1 works well on NSK but must not be executed on  non-NSK platform. So when a user makes JVM to invoke class1 from a non-NSK platform, it should be handled appropraitely. And for doing this, we need to first confirm that we are in non-NSK platform.

Comment: Correct you have a much more complex problem and determining the platform is the easy part.  If you can't even get access to the OS Name, how are you going to change the class path?

Comment: To be be very specific, I have about 8 classes (of about 90 odd classes), which are not supposed to work off-platform as they deal with very specific NSK APIs. So ideal behaviour of my jar would be, if an user tries to invoke any of those 8 classes in say Windows(or any non-NSK platform fro that matter), they they would be intimated that they cannot use them. So in brief, the no of claases that are expected to work off-platform is a subset of the currently present 90 classes which run fine on NSK.

Comment: So even to start a designing the solution above, I need to devise a full-proof way to determine the current platform i am in. I need not worry about CLASSPATH here as I am dealing with only a single jar here. Once platform is determined to be non-NSK, then exception for those 8 calls can be handled easily.

Comment: As discussed above, I cannot use getProperty(). I was looking at the following in some other forums. Can we get the information of OS using <Runtime.getRuntime().exec("something which gives us OS related information"> ?

Comment: @pabitramohan I am confused.  I thought the whole point was so you could determine the right JAR to load, but if this is done for you I don't see the point.

Comment: Loading of jar is not an issue. My current issue is to determine a proper way to determine the OS I am currently in (after which I can go further implementation) which is proving to be tricky as I cannot use getProperty due to aforementioned reason. I need to find some other way to find the OS details.

Comment: If you can't get properties you won't be allowed to run external programs.  That would be insane if you could.  I still don't understand why you need to know this if you know you have the right JAR.

Comment: Let me answer your last qs. Currently I have got a jar which has about 90 classes. This is running fine in our NSK platform. However, one of our customers has asked us to make the jar off-platform. So that he can use this jar in Windows as well. Now, problem is there are some classes(abt 8) which ll not work off-platform(and thats expected). So, to create a check in those 8 classes(checking that they are not being called off-platform) and then throwing a proper exception to the user involves getting to know about which platform we are currently. Does that makes any sense?